# Is there a way to have just one function in views and then put a lot of categories in it with just one path in URL?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

Suppose the following codes are for different categories and they have to have same html file:

```
def dsd(request):
    p=product.objects.filter(category__name='dsd')
    return render(request,'Tools.html',{'p':p})
def dad(request):
    p=product.objects.filter(category__name='dad')
    return render(request,'Tools.html',{'p':p})
def dfd(request):
    p=product.objects.filter(category__name='dfd')
    return render(request,'Tools.html',{'p':p})

def dadfd(request):
    p=product.objects.filter(category__name='dadfd')
    return render(request,'Tools.html',{'p':p})
def dasdfd(request):
    p=product.objects.filter(category__name='dasdfd')
    return render(request,'Tools.html',{'p':p})
def ss(request):
    p=product.objects.filter(category__name='ss')
    return render(request,'Tools.html',{'p':p})
def dasdfad(request):
    p=product.objects.filter(category__name='dasdfad')
    return render(request,'Tools.html',{'p':p})
def dfdfdfed(request):
    p=product.objects.filter(category__name='dfdfdfed')
    return render(request,'Tools.html',{'p':p})
def daaad(request):
    p=product.objects.filter(category__name='daaad')
    return render(request,'Tools.html',{'p':p})
def dddddd(request):
    p=product.objects.filter(category__name='dddddd')
    return render(request,'Tools.html',{'p':p})
```

html file:

```html
    <div class="grid">  
      
             {%for p in p%} 
                    <div class='card'>
                        <img src="{{p.image}}"></img>
                        <p id="id">{{p.description}}</p>
                        <a href="{{p.buy}}" target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>
                            <button><span class="price"> ${{p.price}}</span> buy</button>
                        </a>    




                    </div>

             {%endfor%} 
</div>
```

If I go to my URLs and create different paths for each function and create separate html files with the same code inside of them, then I will be confused.

Is there a way to have just one function in views and then put a lot of categories in it with just one path in URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add needed category as part of url which will let you use it as variable in view.

views.py

```
def tools(request, category):
    p = product.objects.filter(category__name=category)
    return render(request, 'Tools.html', {'p': p})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('tools/<str:category>', tools, name='tools_by_category'),
]
```

then by entering url: `localhost:8000/tools/dddddd` you will get the same result as you would have in your `def dddddd(request)` function.