# Reverse for 'Tools' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['home/(?P<category>[^/]+)\\Z']

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

Based on an answer to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72586573/is-there-a-way-to-have-just-one-function-in-views-and-then-put-a-lot-of-categori)

This is my html code:

```
<a href="{% url 'Tools' %}"><p>Tools</p></a>
```

When I used category like this `def home( request,category)` in my views, I got a positional argument error so I used this :

```
def home( request,**kwargs ):
    p=product.objects.filter(category__name= category)
    return render(request,'home.html',{'p':p})
```

This is URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    
    path('',views.home),
    path('home/<str:category>', views.home,name='Tools'),
    
]
```

But after going to this URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/Tools` I got this error :

```
NoReverseMatch at /home/Tools
Reverse for 'Tools' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['home/(?P<category>[^/]+)\\Z']
```

Why do I get this error?

Or how can I solve this error `home() missing 1 required positional argument: 'category'`

if I want to use this : `def home( request,category)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you see means that `Tools` URL expects one parameter. So the following:

```html
<a href="{% url 'Tools' 'some_category' %}"><p>Tools</p></a>
```

is acceptable. It you want to have `Tools` view without a category, you need another URL that doesn't require it (or regex in existing to allow empty category, but it is more error prone in general):

```py
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
    path('home', views.home, name='Tools'),
    path('home/<str:category>', views.home, name='Tools'),    
]
```

```py
# views.py

def home(request, category=None):  # Note default value
    p = product.objects.all()  # Why is your model class name lowercase?..
    if category is not None:
        p = p.filter(category__name=category)

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'p':p})
```

Also you can use

```
path('home', views.home, {'category': None}, name='Tools')
```

in `urls.py` instead of default argument value.